# Bilingual books post A-level

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, ressources

I have about the standard of A-level French and would like to further my reading ability. What are some good/standard bilingual books to read? I am struggling to work how to best improve my reading abilites post A-level.

Comment: my tags are probably off, but i couldnt find any suitable!

Comment: http://apprendre-anglais-avec-les-livres-bilingues.weebly.com/ — https://livre.fnac.com/n232916/Dictionnaires-et-Langues/Anglais-Ouvrages-bilingues

Answer (score 1):

Googling comes in handy as always. For instance trying Le Petit prince pdf one gets

http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/tringali/documents/st_exupery_le_petit_prince.pdf

and, supposing that your mother tongue is English (The Little Prince pdf)

http://www.yoanaj.co.il/uploadimages/The_Little_Prince.pdf

(I don't think there is any violation of copyright here; at least for the English version.)

Comment: I don't think our nice *St Exupéry* would blame you :D